# Não consigo instalar nada por linhas de comando help

Tags: apt, repository

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_packges_mocrosoft_com_repos_vscodestable-jammy.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.